# Android Soundpool no longer working

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

so I've had an issue I can't quite get my head around. I've been using a static class to hold hold my SoundPool.

e.g.

```
public class Sound 
{

    private static SoundPool sounds;
    private static int charged;

    public static void loadSound(Context context) 
    {
       sounds = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
       charged = sounds.load(context, R.raw.charged, 1);
    }

    public static void playCharged()
    {
       sounds.play(charged, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);

    }
```

Then in the onCreate method of my main Activity ( which extends BaseGameActivity ) I do the following:

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
Sound.loadSound(this);
```

So to play the sound I would usually just go Sound.playCharged() from my Game object that is an attribute of my main activity.  Before, this all worked great. I'm not sure when it stopped working but, I can only assume once I started making major changes. I supported the Google Play services then put my Game object in another activity.

None of the sounds play. However, I found that sounds do play if call the method to play them within a constructor to my game object or other constructors. My assumption is that something is happening once I've initialised everything, as if something is being lost.

Comment: Something to try: create a `SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener` method, and have that log the load status.  Also, log the return value from `sounds.play()`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion! I didn't have one of those included so I will make sure to add the listener for the future. Luckily I have solved the error which was to do with the fact that I added a new activity. In the original Activities onStop method I would release the sounds. Not giving any errors made this difficult to spot.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I eventually managed to solve the problem by not releasing the sounds in the onStop method of my main activity, but the new activity instead that I had created. As the onStop method would be called before starting the 2nd activity messing up with the sounds.